# iOS & Google Analytics: Does pointing to an rss feed register in web analytics?

Tags: rss, ios, google-analytics, feedburner

If an iPhone application has a blog section which parses and displays individual pages from a feedburner feed, will those hits show up in the **web Google Analytics**?

If not, if I add Google Analytics to the iOS application itself, is there a way to combine the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You track the app usage of the blog using the feedburner statistics.

What do you mean by combine the data?

Could you not make a request to the site or blog every time the user opens the blog view to force analytics to count the web hit? Parse the rss feed and then do this.